# Detect single/multi-finger gesture Swiftui

Tags: swiftui, gesture, draggesture

How to detect number of finger interaction with Gesture in SwiftUI `Gesture`. With UIKit we can find number of find it from

```
        let numberOfTouches = panGestureRecognizer.numberOfTouches
```

Any thought?

Comment: Not supported now in SwiftUI. Continue with UIKit + representable if applicable.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will see if we can make same with UIPanGestureRecognizer . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to find my solution using UIKit UIView. Actually made container view(UIVIewRepresentable) which implements the PanGesture. I have used this view to to hold SwiftUI view. I can easily find and able to handle Panning behaviour.